# Where can I find ranges of isotope abundances?

Tags: reference-request, isotope, databases

I'd like to know how much stable isotopes like $\ce{^{13}C}$, $\ce{^2H}$, $\ce{^{17}O}$ and $\ce{^{18}O}$ deviate from their natural abundances in the earth's crust among all possible compounds we may come across, especially organic molecules. I'd like to know a rough minimum and maximum percentage of such isotopes that a given compound is likely to contain, and if possible how likely it is to contain such a percentage. It might be really good to have a histogram showing how common compounds with different percentages of such isotopes are. Does anyone know where I could find such data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am aware of this *range* diagram about $\ce{^{81}Br}$ that appeared in the recurrent (open access) IUPAC recommendations of atomic weights in *Pure and Applied Chemistry*:

[image]

(source: [doi 10.1351/PAC-REP-13-03-02](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2013.85.issue-5/pac-rep-13-03-02/pac-rep-13-03-02.xml))

which cites data of a publication in *Environmental Chemistry* extending a little to $\ce{^{37}Cl}$ ([doi 10.1071/EN10090](http://www.publish.csiro.au/EN/EN10090), open access), too.

Even if the elder (2000) IUPAC compilation in the same journal includes a graphical representation of the *range* in occurrence of $\ce{^2H}$ as known at this time:

[image]

(source: [doi 10.1351/pac200375060683](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2003.75.issue-6/pac200375060683/pac200375060683.xml), open access)

it may be worth to read more in detail, as -- in contrast to the 2011 edition (32 pages) -- the 2000 edition (120 pages) includes a dedicated section "Isotope fractionation from natural processes" and "Element-by-element review of the standard atomic weights" for a detailed view.

---

Otherwise, if you were "just" interested in an overall overview of isotopes, their masses and their percentage of occurrence, NIST has a searchable dedicated database [here](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-weights-and-isotopic-compositions-relative-atomic-masses).

Answer (score 3):

After looking through the sources from the gratefully acknowledged [Buttonwood's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/75990/41328), I also came across [CIAAW](http://www.ciaaw.org/isotopic-abundances.htm), which seems to have some of the best available data for the natural isotope abundance ranges of elements like $\ce{C}$, $\ce{H}$, $\ce{N}$, $\ce{O}$, and $\ce{Cl}$. It is based on *IUPAC Technical Report 2013* [[1](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2015-0503)].

#### References

1. Meija, J.; Coplen, T. B.; Berglund, M.; Brand, W. A.; De, B. P.; Gröning, M.; Holden, N. E.; Irrgeher, J.; Loss, R. D.; Walczyk, T.; et al. Isotopic Compositions of the Elements 2013 (IUPAC Technical Report). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2016**, 88 (3), 293–306. https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2015-0503.